# Express.js req body is undefined

Tags: forms, node.js, post, express

I'm using Express 3.4.4 and my node.js conf looks like this:

Node.js

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(checkCookie);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Login.html

```
<div class="row" id="content">
    <form class="row" action="/login" method="post">
        <div><input type='text' name='username'/></div>
        <div><input type='password' name='password' /></div>
        <div><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Log in"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Post request looks like this

```
Content-Length:27
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Form has needed information in it.

I've tried with app.use(require('connect').bodyParser()); but no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where's checkCookie come from?

Comment: bodyParser() will be deprecated use app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded()); instead of it

Comment: Where's the code that uses `req.body`? @TarekSalah how does that solve this issue?

Comment: where do you place 'app.use(app.router)'?

Comment: @robertklep I don't know if this will solve the issue but this is sugesstion